# Feature selection using PCA for linear regression

Tags: feature-selection, linear-model, lasso, ridge-regression, feature-engineering

I am using PCA to the training data set to do feature selection before applying linear regression to build a classifier model.

1. In this scenario, would it be useful to use ridge regression to ensure that the design matrix is invertible?
2. Does it make sense to use Lasso (not at the same time as using ridge regression) to shrink coeﬃcients to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Principle components regression (PCR) can be hard to interpret but is a very useful tool for predictive modeling, and it tends to validate well.  A real benefit of PCR is that you don't need feature selection, hence a major source of instability vanishes.  And you don't need to worry about inverting an unstable matrix because you only use the first $k$ PCs.

Because the order of PCs is pre-specified (we examine them in order of variation explained in $X$, unlike what stepwise regression and other feature 'selection' methods use), we do not need to penalize for model uncertainty or use anything like *lasso*.  We can enter PCs in descending order of variation in $X$ explained and choose the number of components that optimizes AIC.

Then you fit the model with those PCs and be done.

As with many methods, scaling of predictors is a huge issue.  We routinely scale $X$s by their standard deviations when computing PCs but this can be questioned.

More about PC regression is in my [Regression Modeling Strategies book and course notes](http://fharrell.com/links).

But your post mentions both "linear regression" and "classifier".  These are at odds with each other, and a "classifier" is something that outputs a forced choice (as opposed to a probability estimator such as logistic regression).  Please edit the title and text to state what you are really doing.  I assume it is prediction with a linear model, and "classifier" has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: It is regression only, but using the regression model for classiffication.

Comment: Regression is used for prediction, not for classification.  Clarify.

Answer (score 2):

As Frank said, if you use PCA to create a few variables, you should not have inversion problems (especially if you use an orthogonal rotation), nor will you have collinearity (which ridge regression helps with).

But I would not say PCA is a good method of variable selection. PCA creates linear combinations of variables that capture as much as possible of the variance in the full list of variables. Those combinations won't (usually) be very helpful in variable selection, if your goal is to have a model with the original variables.

Model building and variable selection is a huge topic, discussed here many times. When advising people, I always try to get them to avoid *any* automatic method because automatic methods don't let you use your brain. If you must use an automatic method, LASSO is a good choice, but you would do that on the original variables, not the principal components.

Finally, if you do decide to go with some kind of dimension reduction, I'd consider partial least squares, which is sort of like PCA regression, but also accounts for relations with the DV.

Comment: _lasso_ has a problem with stability (reproducibility of "found" features).